Incorporating a websocket in my react-native application and having it update a screen if the screen is currently active
I have a websocket that updates data and it exists on my main screen that has a tab navigator. If one of my tabs is open i would like for it to update in real time. I've been having some trouble on making it react to changes outside of the screen.
My current theory is using a context and updating a value there and I put a useEffect on the tab in question to react to it.
my loadData() method is getting the new data from an AsyncStorage. the screenUpdate method updates the context and I see a log that shows it changing. I would want to see the loadData method be run in response to the state.update being changed but nothing happens currently. I put a test of the code below
 const {state, screenUpdate} = useContext(MyContext);

useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
     var data = loadOrder();
     setReciept(data);
     console.log('Dave felt the update')
   })();
 }, [state.update]);

 doTheThing = async() => {
   console.log('I did the thing')
   await screenUpdate();


   console.log('Check value')
   console.log(state.update)
 }




 return (
       <View style={[currentStyles.container]}>
           <Button title="Update screen" onPress={() =>{doTheThing()}}/>
         />
   </View>                               
   );
 }




If anyone has a better solution or advice I'd be appreciative

You should have the useEffect in the parent/root component with the appropriate dependecies. You can then utilize the useContext hook to update in real time across the components. For example, a commonly named root component in react is App.js; if I was on tab A and the websocket changed data on tab B, I would need for the useEffect in the app to run when state changed, according to the dependency. Then you set the context and the context is spread throughout. Its all a matter of the right dependencies for the appropriate trigger of the useEffect and sharing those changes to the right componnt
